# How to sort and create raster stack from multiple daily TRMM netcdf files

Tags: r, r-raster

I tried this to extract the data from `trmm` daily nc4 files.

```
path<-"F:/TRMM/test"
setwd(path)
## open all `trmm` rainfall data files from folder
trmm_files = list.files(path,pattern = '*.nc', full.names = TRUE)
#I want only HQprecipitation variable from nc4 file.
trmm_stack <- stack(trmm_files, varname = "HQprecipitation")
```

But the `trmm_stack` lost its coordinate system while stacking. Hence, I had to assign it. Furthermore, how can I verify whether the raster-stack is sorted according to dates and in which order? I need a time-series data.

```
crs(trmm_stack) <- CRS('+init=EPSG:4326')             # also it was rotated
trmm_stack_flip <- t(flip(trmm_stack, direction='y'))
```

Then I create a matrix of latitude-longitude coordinates for locations

```
lat<- c(26.0166666, 25.674444, 25.5666666, 25.6666666, 26.18, 25.57)
lon <- c(91.85, 91.9025, 91.8666666, 91.8833333, 91.75, 91.9)
xym <- cbind(lat, lon)
```

and extracted the cell values from `trmm_stack` using

```
data2 <- extract(trmm_stack, xym, method='simple', buffer = NULL, small = FALSE, cellnumbers = FALSE,
        fun=NULL, na.rm=TRUE, df = FALSE, factors = FALSE)
```

[image: see image]

Then I get an output table with column names ending with layer number. But I do not know whether extraction was done at the exact location and date order as time series as I wanted. How to verify this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The order of the RasterStack is the same as the order of the filenames. You can check your filenames (and sort them if need be, but be careful with sorting numbers represented as characters (10 comes before 2).

Note that you make a mistake here:

```
xym <- cbind(lat, lon)
```

It should be

```
xym <- cbind(lon, lat)
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying on file ordering. Can u also tell me how to verify whether my extracted values are representing exact location given in  xym matrix of latitude-longitude coordinates for locations ? and not just random values from other locations?

Comment: The values you are extracting are for the locations you specify. You specified them incorrectly (see my expanded answer)